# as3 passing content of one text filed to another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, var

I'm tying to pass the contents of

> B1L_bnt.text

to

> buddy_txt.text

Can anyone tell me what am doing Wong here?

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        /*container_mcM.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);*/
        var clickedObject:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
        var bobby = Object(root).littlepicker.B1L_bnt.text;

        if (clickedObject.name == 'frd_bnt1')
        {
            Object(root).BFFwho.buddy_txt.text = "bobby";
            Object(root).gotoAndPlay(15);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        /*container_mcM.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);*/
        var clickedObject:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
        var bobby = Object(root).littlepicker.B1L_bnt.text;

        if (clickedObject.name == 'frd_bnt1')
        {
            Object(root).BFFwho.buddy_txt.text = bobby;
            Object(root).gotoAndPlay(15);

        }
```

The issue was that you were declaring a variable named `bobby`. When you were trying to set the text of `buddy_txt`you were setting it to a literal String 'bobby' instead of the value of the variable.